# Display the value of a variable in itself

Tags: ruby, quine

I am doing a quine in Ruby that will display its own code in a new file. I'm trying to do like the following to print the variable itself in the new file:

```
$var = "Some Code%c$var = %c%s%c % [10,34,$var,34,10]%cSome Code" % [10,34,$var,34,10]
```

The `$var` variable is empty in the new file, and this is what I want:

```
Some Text
$var = "Some Code%c$var = %c%s%c % [10,34,$var,34,10]%cSome Code" % [10,34,$var,34,10]
Some Text
```

When I launch it, I get this in the new file:

```
Some Code
$var = "" % [10,$var,10]
Some Code
```

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the percent sign (`%%`) located within the string and also wrap the `$var` assignment expression in parentheses so it's available for the following interpolation like so:

```rb
($var = "Some Code%c($var = %c%s%c) %% [10,34,$var,34,10]%cSome Code") % [10,34,$var,34,10]
```

This should result in the following:

```rb
>> ($var = "Some Code%c($var = %c%s%c) %% [10,34,$var,34,10]%cSome Code") % [10,34,$var,34,10]
=> "Some Code\n($var = \"Some Code%c($var = %c%s%c) %% [10,34,$var,34,10]%cSome Code\") % [10,34,$var,34,10]\nSome Code"
```

Comment: Hello ! It tried to do like you said, but this time it displays all the `%c` and `%s`, but not the new lines or the variable itself... I have this in the new file: `Some Code%c($var = %c%s%c) %% [10,34,$var,34,10]%cSome Code`

Comment: If you can provide a little more information I might be able to further help... how are you running/excuting this? Eg. what commands are you running, etc. What version of Ruby are you running this in? Is this the full script or is there more to it?